# DbContext Log is not intercepting SaveChanges() Generated SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, dbcontext, entity-framework-6.1

The [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) article from MSDN describes the use of the Log property for logging SQL including SQL generated by the `SaveChanges()` method for EF6+.

I am trying to intercept all generated sql from my Context class which inherits from DbContext. The interception works fine for everything except the SQL which is generated by the SaveChanges() method.

**Is DbContext.Database.Log the correct property to use for logging this?**

**Is there another way to log the SQL generated by the SaveChanges() method?**

```
using (Context c = new Context())
{
    //setup logging to debugger
    c.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);

    //generate query
    var query = c.SomeTable.Where(x => x.Abc == "A" && x.Zyx == "Z");

    //enumerate query - generated SQL is logged to debugger correctly
    var items = query.ToList();

    //modify entities
    items.ForEach(t => t.Timestamp = DateTime.Now);

    //get number of changed entities: Outputs "Number of Changed Entities: 3"
    var changedEntries = c.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
    Debug.WriteLine("Number of Changed Entities: {0}", changedEntries.Count());

    //save changes - generated SQL is NOT logged to debugger
    c.SaveChanges();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found out where the problem was. I was using a Context which is derived from DBContext, and which had overridden the SaveChanges() method. Inside the overridden method, it was re-routing the DbContext.Database.Log to a string builder, instead of the debugger.

Comment: I think that it actually doesn't save anything. `Timestamp` is typically a property that is mapped as `Computed`, so it's not updated. Try to update some other property.

Comment: I checked, and it does actually update the rows. I can see that the context contains entities which have changed, and the changes are propogated to the database when i call save changes. To be sure, I also tried changing other properties, but no sql is shown.

Comment: I found the cause, finally. Update is in the question. Thanks for your help @GertArnold

Answer (score 0):

The Context, which derives from DbContext, was overriding the SaveChanges() method. Inside the overridden method, it was re-routing the DbContext.Database.Log to a string builder, instead of the debugger.